# Title Case in French — Majuscules Dans Les Titres

Tags: majuscules, titres

Should I capitalize the first letter of "small words" in titles in French?

In the title of this question, "in" is lower case in English. Does French have a similar format? Should words like "le", "de", "un" remain as lower case?

---

Dois-je écrire la première lettre des petits mots avec une majuscule en français ?

Dans le titre de cette question, « in » est écrit en minuscules en anglais. Est-ce la même chose en français ? Les mots comme « le », « de », « un » doivent-ils rester minuscules ?

Comment: Capital letters appear in French book titles (rules are however different from English ones), but never in section or headline titles (except for the very first letter of the title, of course). I did not edit the title of this question because it's relevant to the question, but it actually hurts a little bit to read French with capitals on every word.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, I think that could be an answer. Especially if you could explain the rules of book titles a little :)

Comment: :D I Imagine It's The Same Pain I Get When I See Sentences Written Like This In English!

Comment: Ne peut-on pas retirer les majuscules dans la partie française du titre ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Selon le *Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie nationale*, on trouve plusieurs cas possibles :

- D'une manière générale, seul le premier mot comporte une capitale :
  « À la recherche du temps perdu. »
- Si le titre commence par un article défini, seul celui-ci prend une majuscule :
  « Le roi s'amuse. »
- Si le titre se compose de deux termes en opposition ou comparaison, tous deux prennent une majuscule si l'un des deux exige la majuscule :
  « La Belle et la Bête. »
- Le premier substantif et les adjectifs et adverbes qui le précèdent :
  « Les Très Riches Heures du duc de Berry. »
- Les mêmes règles s'appliquent pour les titres qui contiennent un autre titre :
  « Le Mariage de Figaro ou la Folle Journée. »

Comment: C'est plus complex que j'ai pensé! Je vais devoir lire la suite.

Comment: @JamesWebster: Effectivement. Je n'ai extrait qu'une partie, l'article sur les titres comporte plus de cinq pages!

Comment: Ah oui, c'est tordu comme règle ça. Preuve que c'est bien du français :D

Comment: Devons-nous créer le tag *majusculite* (excès de capitalisation) ?

Comment: @RomainVALERI: ;-)

Comment: Ok je comprends les règles, mais pourquoi des majuscules supplémentaires dans "Les Très Riches Heures..." et pas dans la "Le roi s'amuse" ? Est-ce un choix libre ou bien y-a-t-il un autre critère ?

Comment: @XouDo: Je ne suis pas l'auteur du lexique cité. Je pense qu'en appliquant la règle 3 « Heures » prend une majuscule car « Berry » étant un nom propre il prend nécessairement une majuscule. Puis en appliquant la règle 4, les adjectifs qui précèdent « Heures » doivent prendre une majuscule. C'est peut-être un peu tordu mais c'est comme ça que je comprends.

Answer (score 5):

For your example I think the correct case is
"Majuscule dans les titres"

We always capitalize the first letter of the fist title word. No capital for other word.

> **U**n amour de coccinelle, *Walt Disney movie.*

If title begin with "small word" in in french "un article défini" and there isn't a sentence we capitalize the small word and the first word

> **L**es **M**ains sales, *Jean-Paul Sartre. play*

if there is an adjective before the name there capilize too

> **L**e **G**rand **É**cart, *Jean Cocteau short story.*

When the title consists of coordinated names, we put a capital letter to each of the names and possibly in the adjectives which precede them.

> **L**e **C**orbeau et le **R**enard, *La Fontaine fable*.

For more information follow the link below (in french) :
http://sites.univ-lyon2.fr/lettres/zdoc-varia/MajusculesInBiblio.pdf

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia suggests](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_des_majuscules_en_fran%C3%A7ais#R.C3.A8gles_traditionnelles) that it's governed by about 10 rules-and-exceptions (maybe too many to copy-and-paste into this answer), but in summary not only 'small' words but others too should be lower case.

Comment: Le site est très complet