# Is the title "La Voie lactée" the proper capitalization of the French equivalent to the English title "The Milky Way"?

Tags: majuscules

I'm seeing differing capitalization for the title "La Voie lactée" or "La Voie Lactée" and need to know which is more correct, or absolutely correct. The English equivalent for the title would be "The Milky Way" Many scientific, astronomical, cinematic, and other websites offer variant capitalization, and perhaps varied when within a sentence as opposed to a title. I am interested in the proper capitalization as a title, as of a book or article. I previously used the word title in my original question, but may have not stressed it enough.

Comment: Duplicate of [Title Case in French — Majuscules Dans Les Titres](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12835/title-case-in-french-majuscules-dans-les-titres)

Comment: What kind of title are we discussing about? Note that as a proper noun it always requires at least one capital letter.

Answer (score 3):

In general, we only capitalize the first word in a proper noun (unless one of the next words also requires capitalization). For example, "la République française", "l'Assemblée nationale" (but "le Royaume de Belgique" because "Belgique" is itself a proper noun). So the proper way would be "la Voie lactée". An adjective would only be capitalized if it is *before* the noun it qualifies (e.g. "le Nouveau Testament").

Comment: The French-English Science and Technology Dictionary, DeVries and Hochman has an entry that supports your answer. Thank you