# Can I leave out the articles in a presentation?

Tags: articles, typographie

Is it common practice to leave out the articles in slides for a presentation in French and would it be acceptable in an academic setting?
I have often seen this in English presentations, and was wondering if it is the same in French.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving out **all** the articles would be odd but leaving the initial one is common, and possibly the rule.

For example, we would just use *Introduction*, *Méthodologie*, *Analyse*, *Étude*, *Conclusion* as slide titles, certainly never *L'introduction*, *La conclusion*.

See also [Do you need to use an article for every noun when writing a title?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/51240/do-you-need-to-use-an-article-for-every-noun-when-writing-a-title)

Comment: I agree with jiliagre on the first article that would feel weird, but after that, it probably would feel broken.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no. It's going to feel broken. But can you give examples of what you have in mind? It would be easier if we could ground the discussion in concrete examples.