# Why is "French Language" translated as "Langue française" instead of "Langue Française"?

Tags: traduction, majuscules, titres

I see that "French Language" is translated as "Langue française" instead of "Langue Française" on this SE:

[image]

Why the casing difference? Since "French Language" uses title case, why wouldn't the French translation also use the title case (i.e., "Langue Française")?

Comment: [Title Case in French — Majuscules Dans Les Titres](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12835/title-case-in-french-majuscules-dans-les-titres)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

French and English have completely different systems for capitalizing words in titles.

In English, there are several systems that differ slightly; they are all along the lines of: capitalize the first and last words and all other words in the title except conjunctions, prepositions, and articles. For example:

> The Tall Blond Man with One Black Shoe,
> The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe.

In French, there are also several systems you can use, as described in the answers to [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12835/title-case-in-french-majuscules-dans-les-titres). You always capitalize the first word. In one system, you leave the rest lowercase. In another common system, if the first word is a definite article, you capitalize the first noun, any adjectives before it, and any nouns on an equal footing with it (e.g., joined to the first noun by *et* or *ou*).

For example,

> Le Grand Blond avec une chaussure noire,
> Le Lion, la Sorcière blanche et l'Armoire magique.

I don't believe any of the French systems would capitalize *française* in *Langue française*, as it comes after the noun it modifies.

Comment: Beside the point, but in English, not all systems capitalize the last word. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case) has details; MLA and APA styles don't capitalize it.

Comment: In books and film titles, the first word is capitalised, and if the first word is the definite article, then the following noun is capitalised; if that noun is _preceded_ by an adjective, that is capitalised, if it is followed by a adjective, that is _not_ capitalised.  So: "L'Ancienne Femme", "La Femme ancienne", "Un femme ancienne"

Comment: @J.J.Green: that does seem to be the rule, so the answer I link to in my question is incorrect. I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer is not about capitalizing words in [*titles*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_des_majuscules_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Titres_d%E2%80%99%C5%93uvres_ou_de_p%C3%A9riodiques) but for its simplest possible convention, which would be similar to a situation where a sentence begins with the phrase in question.] For the same reason writing "<strike>(the) french language</strike>" in English would be inacurate: convention and usage (and it would be real strange if a site dedicated to the French language would do away with its basic tenets from the get go). Contrary to *demonyms* (*un [Français](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais), une Française*), *language names* in French don't take the initial capital irrespective of whether the noun (*le [français](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fran%C3%A7ais#Nom_commun)*) or the adjective (*la langue [française](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fran%C3%A7ais#Adjectif)*) is used to refer to them ([*Wikipédia*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentil%C3%A9#Usage) (1), [*Wikipédia*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_des_majuscules_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Langues) (2), LBU14 § 99 a 3° : "La majuscule dans les gentilés est importante parce qu'elle permet de les distinguer des noms de langues, lesquels s'écrivent par la minuscule"; see also [*Ac.9*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9F1526), [*TLFi*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fran%C3%A7ais) showcasing this convention).

---

Different languages, different [conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization).

Comment: Thanks, my rationale was as follows: since "French Language" uses title case, why wouldn't the French translation also use the title case (i.e., "Langue Française")?

Comment: @viande-à-chien: I actually think French is more flexible with capitalization in titles. In English, there's essentially just one way to do it: all the words of a title are capitalized except for articles, conjunctions, and some prepositions. In French, there are several systems you could use — see [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12835/title-case-in-french-majuscules-dans-les-titres). But française wouldn't be capitalized in any of these systems.

Answer (score 1):

I guess here "française" is an adjective and comes after "Langue" so no need for uppercase whereas in English it comes before "Language" so an uppercase is necessary/recommended.

The real question then is : why an uppercase on "Language" ?

Comment: In English, it has nothing to do with ajective-noun order. See [Peter Shor's answer](/a/51796/11413).

Comment: `I don't believe any of the French systems would capitalize française in Langue française, as it comes after the noun it modifies`. I said more or less the same thing he said, except I used the word "adjective" for "modificator".